# Find comparing two DateTime field on Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to compare two field of the same document but I need add some seconds to one of them.

My query is:

```
db.getCollection('period').find({
    $where: function() {
        return this.dt_stop <= this.dt_start.getTime() + 60000 
    } 
})
```

But I get the next error:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "TypeError: this.dt_last_start is undefined :\n@:1:15\n",
    "code" : 139,
    "codeName" : "JSInterpreterFailure"
}
```

I don't get to add second to field. Any idea?

**---SOLVE--**
The problem was some documents whose this.dt_stop didn't exists. The final code:

```
db.getCollection('period').find(
{
    "$and" : [ 
        {"dt_stop" : {"$exists" : true}},
        {"dt_start" : {"$exists" : true}}, 
        { $where: function() {return this.dt_end.getTime() <= this.dt_begin.getTime()+60000} 
        } 
    ]
})
```

Comment: Is `dt_stop` a date field or a number (timestamp)?

Comment: dt_stop is assigned with ISODate(), for example ISODate("2018-02-13T09:47:48.868Z"). How can I to know the type of field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dt_stop` is an ISODate and you are comparing it to a timestamp (this.dt_start.getTime() + 60000).

try this

```
db.getCollection('period').find({
    $where: function() {
        return this.dt_stop.getTime() <= this.dt_start.getTime() + 60000 
    } 
})
```

Comment: It don't work... I'm not sure the sentence db.getCollection('period').find({dt_stop  :{"$lt": date}}); can be use  in a $where function.

Comment: I get a error : TypeError: this.dt_start is undefined : @(shell):1:9.

Comment: @Miliow i edited the answer again, can you try it now?

Comment: Also if this also fails can you please post the db table schema?

Comment: I get the error "TypeError: this.dt_last_stop is undefined"  again.  My schema is: _id string, _class string, dt_start object ==is_Date==, dt_stop object ==is_Date==, space string, Relacionado object[ $ref string , $id string ]

Comment: Ok... The problem was some documents with this.dt_stop didn't exists. The final code:
      db.getCollection('period').find({"$and" : [
{"dt_stop" : {"$exists" : true}}, 
{"dt_start" : {"$exists" : true}},
{
    $where: function() {
        return this.dt_end.getTime() <= this.dt_begin.getTime()+60000 
    }
} 
]})